# Getting information from a .csv array

Tags: java, csv

I have a .CSV file with rows for [ID], [NAME], [LASTNAME], [EMAIL], [GENDER]. There are 1000 entries

**I need the code to give me the total number of ID-s in the list.
After this is complete, the code must separately show FIRST 10 in the specific array.**

Currently, it only shows the full ID-section in all of it's extent.
The .lenght() does not seem to work to count the total, it counts all the numbers in the array instead.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String fileName="test.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName);

    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        inputStream.next();
        while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
            String data = inputStream.next();
            String[] values = data.split(",");

            System.out.println(values[0]);
            
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```